# What are the differences between the different ways of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

These days I've been trying to implement the MVVM pattern in my UWP apps without additional framework as a learning exercise. Though I still to struggle to understand the implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so I'm reading about it quite a lot at the moment. I came upon very different ways of doing it but I fail to understand the difference between them.

This is what csharpcorner advises [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-with-mvvm/):

```cs
        public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged  
    {  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)  
        {  
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;  
            storage = value;  
            this.OnPropertyChaned(propertyName);  
            return true;  
        }  

        private void OnPropertyChaned(string propertyName)  
        {  
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;  
            if (eventHandler != null)  
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
        }  
    }
```

This is how John Shews does it in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/) blog post from msdn:

```cs
public class NotificationBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // SetField (Name, value); // where there is a data member
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] String property 
           = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(property);
            return true;
        }

        // SetField(()=> somewhere.Name = value; somewhere.Name, value) 
        // Advanced case where you rely on another property
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(T currentValue, T newValue, Action DoSet,
            [CallerMemberName] String property = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(currentValue, newValue)) return false;
            DoSet.Invoke();
            RaisePropertyChanged(property);
            return true;
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) 
            { 
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); 
            }
        }
    }

    public class NotificationBase<T> : NotificationBase where T : class, new()
    {
        protected T This;

        public static implicit operator T(NotificationBase<T> thing) { return thing.This; }

        public NotificationBase(T thing = null)
        {
            This = (thing == null) ? new T() : thing;
        }
}
```

And this is what I've been advised by @Tomtom for a previous question on SO:

```cs
public abstract class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly Dictionary<string, object> mapping;

  protected NotifyBase()
  {
    mapping = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  }

  protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    mapping[propertyName] = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
  }

  protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    if(mapping.ContainsKey(propertyName))
      return (T)mapping[propertyName];
    return default(T);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemeberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone explain the differences and tell me if one of these implementations is better ? Especially:

- What's the use of the `Dictionary` in Tomtom's version ?
- What does the `SetProperty` overload do in John's version ?
- Why do the first two examples not have a `Get` method like the last one ? Is it not necessary ?
- Why does John add a `NotificationBase<T>` class ? Is it an important thing that the others missed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't guess what `NotificationBase<T>` is supposed to accomplish. It should have been commented. It looks like the dictionary is meant to let you avoid declaring private backing fields, which IMO is silly. I suspect both were done because some people just like adding unnecessary complexity for its own sake. The SetProperty overload with DoSet() lets you pass in a lambda that only gets executed if the value changes. There may be some use for that.

Comment: The only idea behind these is to wrap setting properties of an object in a *generic* `SetProperty` so that you don't have to tediously repeat raising `OnPropertyChanges` from mutliple properties in the very same way. This looks completely optional and personally I don't think I would follow any of these.

Comment: About the NotificationBase<T>, John adds further down in the article :

"Using the NotificationBase<T> is a convenient way to wrap existing business objects that don’t already support INPC"

Comment: @MarcelBarc Hmmmmm.

Comment: @Ed Not that convenient imo, and surely confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tomtom version appears to be an attempt to use a dictionary instead of fields; this is *flexible* - kinda like `ExpandoObject` - but it can be surprisingly inefficient, involving lots of extra objects (the dictionary, the keys, *plus* whatever tree structures the dictionary uses) *and* lots of CPU cycles spent looking things up *constantly*.

If you have *lots of potential fields* (and by lots I mean as in hundreds), but you typically only use 3 at a time, then this might be an effective solution. Likewise, if the structure is *entirely dynamic* (perhaps based on input data that you don't control, presumably paired with `ICustomTypeDescriptor`), then it might be useful. The combination of dictionary and `CallerMemberName` suggests this *is* intended to be used with properties, though, which makes this ... very odd.

But in general: I'd use the simpler `ref` field version. The reason this doesn't have a `Get` method is that the caller can *already* just use the field directly.

So: if you want this kind of code, I'd use:

```cs
public class MyType : BaseModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    private int _id;
    public string Id {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the Tomtom version is trying to avoid having to declare the fields, i.e.

```cs
public class MyType : BaseModel
{
    public string Name {
        get => GetProperty<string>();
        set => SetProperty<string>(value);
    }

    public string Id {
        get => Get<int>();
        set => SetProperty<int>(value);
    }
}
```

But... yeah, don't do that. In addition to everything else, this ends up boxing all the value-types. Fields are fine...

Comment: I bet the dictionary stunt is just meant to save typing of backing field declarations, at the cost of runtime overhead and embarrassing code. I've known guys who might think that was clever.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't look at it without wanting to scream... all those boxes!

Comment: But the underscore key is *all the way over there!* And who knows what snippets are?

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer. So if I get it right, in this case, the simpler, the better !